# htaccess rewrite after redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a site which uses htaccess to rewrite all pages to the index page with a hash which is then used to serve up content. The file looks like this....

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?urlpath=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I am now moving some of the pages of the site, however if I add a redirect such as....

```
Redirect 301 /blog /new_location/blog/
```

I am running into problems with the resulting url looking like

https://mydomain/new_location/blog/urlpath=blog.php

Can anyone suggest a way that I get the page to redirect to mydomain/new_location/blog/ and then run the rewrite on the new url.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to get this working using a combination of Redirect and Rewrite like so....

```
Redirect 301 /blog /new_location/blog

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?urlpath=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Maybe not the neatest solution, but it work!

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteRule` and `Redirect` are from different Apache modules, so run at different times in the processing, not in the order they appear in the configuration. You're best off sticking to one module or the other, by using the `[R]` flag to `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteRule /blog(.*) /new_location/blog$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: I have changed the Redirect to a RewriteRule but it didn't work as hoped as the new url (/new_location/blog) is not being passed to the index page, so it is trying to look up the page content using the original url (/blog) finding no content.